# Is there any way to end threads simultaneously?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio, semaphore

I have a program (in c++ WIN32 with VisualStudio19) in which i have several threads with the same HANDLE. 
Somethink like this:

```
father
{
    while(true)
        HANDLE son=createThread...

}

son
{
    //The son may be waiting in a semaphore
}
```

Is there any way to end the "life" of the threads simultaneously? Like you do in UNIX with sigterm or sigkill.
The threads may be waiting in a semaphore

Comment: I think that is not possible and that you must implement it yourself. Keep all Handles in a container and call `TerminateThread`.

Comment: This is for a College project and we can't use TerminateThread

Comment: "in which i have several threads with the same HANDLE" - that sounds bad. How are you distinguishing the threads if they all share the same identifier?

Comment: The "correct" way to program child threads is have them occasionally check a "termination event", and have the father signal it when they should exist.

Comment: @NadavS you mean "exit", not "exist".

Comment: I'll check "termination event" and try to use more HANDLES, thanks

Comment: the "termination event" is what I do in real life, and calling `TerminateThread` is illegal and punishable by death.  I suggested it only because OP mentioned `sigkill` and it's kind of the same.

Comment: @FaustoSánchezHoya Maybe the "semaphore" is the termination event I'm talking about

Comment: your question have no sense without additional context.

Comment: @NadavS i've used the "termination event" and it finally works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Normally on Windows if you can't avoid such need, you'll run all threads to be terminated to a separate process, and terminate that process - no matter if it is just one thread or more.